# Ubuntu on Mac stuck on home screen (nomodeset already tried)

Tags: boot, macbook-pro, nomodeset

I have an old macbook pro. I think from  2010.
Because apple doesn't let me update their OS, this piece of hardware became useless (besides being in good shape).
Anyway, lately, I thought it was time to install Ubuntu and get a new life for this machine.

I downloaded the image from Ubuntu website into a USB.

I started the instalation without trouble, system asked me to restart, Ubuntu launched, but nothing else happens. I have the jellyfish wallpaper but I can't do anything else.

Then, looking on the Internet, I found some potential incompatibilities with graphic cards. I tried the nomodeset hack but after pressing F10, same result, can't go further the splash screen.

Any aditonal ideas?